# authlogic open-id with Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Has anyone been able to get the authlogic open-id gems to work in **Rails 3**. I am using Rails 3.2 and running into various issues.

I will post the solutions I find as I make progress.

Comment: Have you looked into the Sorcery gem for open-id? I'm using it on a few applications and is very easy to incorporate.

Comment: A.K. Can you expand on these "various issues"? There may be more than one problem with this to solve.

@kobaltz , would you be so kind as to point to a guide on using Sorcery, this alternative may be an answer to the problem.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/283-authentication-with-sorcery

Comment: There are some things out to date on the railscasts. The initial setup, I do through the gem's github page. The sessions login and validations is fine to use from the railscasts episode.

Comment: I am moving omniauth with the google_oauth2 provider. It pretty much works out of the box. Use https://github.com/zquestz/authpoint.git as a starting point.